# this in javascript not populating data as expected

Tags: javascript, oop, dom, object, this

My code -

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var firstObject = {
sayHello : function(){
        document.write("My name is "+ this.myName +"<br>");
},
myName : "Swapnesh Sinha"
};
var secondObject = {myName : "Sanjay Sinha"};

document.write("First one " + firstObject.sayHello() );
document.write("<br>");
document.write("Second one "+ secondObject.myName); 
</script>
```

**Source** - http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

Expecting output -

```
First one Swapnesh Sinha
Second one Sanjay Sinha
```

Unexpected Output (from my sense)-

```
My name is Swapnesh Sinha
First one undefined
Second one Sanjay Sinha
```

Let me know the case why it returns `undefined` however source is mentioning to return name ? or something I am getting wrong from my side

Comment: Your sayHello function does not return anything, it just excecutes a `document.write()`, thus by default it returns `undefined`

Comment: replace document.write() with return in your sayHello function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the working fiddle**: [JsFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/pDXnU/)

Here is what you fail to understand, as most jQuery developers: JavaScript scoping.

Basically, in order for a property to be accessed via `this`, it has to be nested in the `Object.prototype`.

**Correction**

When you define the object properties inline, calling `this` will still point to the right object. However, the pattern I gave you, even though less popular, is a much neater and better approach.

The `prototype` is the JavaScript way of OOP. If you are looking for solid OOP style JS and for proper definition of models, improved code maintainability and better coding style, it is preferred to define classes using the pattern I gave you, as it will allow you to make a strong distinction between static functions and classes. It is also the natural flow of JavaScript, where everything is an object.

In high level JavaScript programming(powerful Ajax applications or applications where for one reason or the other the browser has to perform more advanced computation), the below style is always preferred. Static functions placed under a namespace are still defined separately:

```
var namespace = {};
namespace.firstStaticFunc = function() {/*do stuff etc;*/};
namespace.secondStaticFunc = function() { return !1; };
```

The only reason why you use your definition pattern is enums and hash maps. For instance:

```
var typesOfChicken = {
    RED: 'red',
    BLUE: 'blue'
};
```

The above is always used for things like internationalization and avoidance of hard coded values. Also, it helps JS minifiers to a better job. Given the above, you can say:

```
console.log(typesOfChicken.RED);// will print red.
console.log("red");// wil still print red
```

But, when I want to change red to something else, using enums I only have to do a single change. Also, the minifier can replace `typesOfChicken.RED` with a.b, whereas `"RED"` will always be "RED". It's unminifiable.

```
var firstObject = function() { };
firstObject.prototype.myName = "Swapnesh Sinha";//this will not be nested as an instance property.
firstObject.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    alert(this.myName);// will now correctly display Swapnesh Sinha
};
// to use your first object.
var instance = new firstObject();
instance.sayHello();
```

To properly make use of scope, use the pattern I gave you, which is an Object Oriented pattern and the right approach to defining classes in JS.

And now you have a great way to organize your JavaScript code, it's fair easier to maintain, scope is a lot more obvious and most important of all you can immediately make a distinction between static functions and classes.

Comment: Er, this isn't correct. The only problem he has is not understanding how returning and document.write() works, as others have suggested. You are straight up wrong. You don't need to put things on the prototype to use `this` inside of a function call refers to the object that's calling the function (such as firstObject). you don't need to prototype at all.

Comment: But you're literally saying incorrect things. You're lying to him. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: This sentence is false: "In your case, you are doing a simple value assignation, so inside your sayHello function, this is actually pointing to the window object and not to the firstObject." It is untrue. Inside of that sayHello function, this refers to firstObject. You can tell that from the output.

Answer (score 1):

In your first `document.write`, you call a function, and ask the return value of the function to be concatenated to the string "First one ".

The function is evaluated, at which point "My name is Swapnesh Sinha" gets outputed via `document.write` call inside the object. That function call however does not return a value, hence it is `undefined`, and that gets concatenated to "First one", which is then printed.

Comment: In other words, replace `document.write` inside `sayHello` to `return`

Comment: Just to clarify, the function does return a value of type undefined.

Answer (score 0):

replace document.write() with return in your sayHello function